# Create boolean twin field automatically for Django model fields

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have models with many fields. For a large amount of those fields (let's say around 20) but not all of them I would like to automatically create a twin `BooleanField` each.

Some requirements:

- The fields are of different type (e.g. `CharField`, `DateField`, ...)
- In the future there will be new fields added, which is why I want to create this generic solution such that I'll only have to add the main field and mark it for adding a twin
- Ideally I would like to be able to use the same ORM syntax for filtering and such as if I had manually defined the boolean twin
- Most of the times just the fields themselves are needed, only very rarely the boolean twin

Given the following model

```py
from django.db.models import model

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ignore_field = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
    my_field = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
```

I would like to automatically add the field:

```py
    is_fixed_my_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

### What I have considered:

**1. [composite-fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-composite-field/)**

The problem I see with that approach is that I will need to define such a composite field for every field type manually and I am also not sure if I can pass kwargs. Also, I don't think I can keep the default syntax for queries. Instead I'd have to add this additional level at every filter.

```py
class FixedField(CompositeField):
    value = models.Charfield()  # could I even add the kwargs?
    is_fixed = models.BooleanField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ignore_field = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
    my_field = FixedField()
```

**2. [custom fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/)**
My dream is to create a custom field that I could use like the following:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ignore_field = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
    my_field = FixableField(models.Charfield, max_length=30)

MyModel.objects.filter(is_fixed_my_field=True)
m = MyModel(my_field="foo")
print(m.is_fixed_my_field)  # False
```

Obviously it doesn't work with someting like

```py
class FixableField:
    def __init__(self, model, field_class: models.Field, *args, **kwargs):
        setattr(model, f"is_fixed_{cannot_get_the_field_name}", models.BooleanField)
        field_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

because the class isn't really instantiated during migration generation as far as I understand.

**Is my dream possible at all?**

*Note1: I'm using postgres in the background.*

*Note2: I'm currently using Django 1.11, but if a solution only works with a more recent version I am interested in that too.*